# When executing an SSH command in Jenkins, the bash profile is different to when connecting over SSH with the same user

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, jenkins, npm

I'm trying to run some CLI nodejs commands on a remote server using the Jenkins SSH exec functionality.

I'm receiving an error message when trying to run forever, which I had installed globally with npm.

*Edit*: the error was; `-bash: forever: command not found`.

Connecting over SSH as root and running `which npm` returns;

```
/root/local/bin/npm
```

Whereas via Jenkins, with the same command as root returns;

```
/usr/bin/npm
```

I've tried setting bash variables, but these seem to be inconsistent across the two connection mediums too.

Both were installed using the top method detailed here; https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814#file-node-and-npm-in-30-seconds-sh

Comment: I have a very similar problem now, did you find a solution for this @Dan Steele?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ssh user@host -t 'bash -l -c "forever"'
```

You can read with `man ssh`:

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of
>   a login shell.

No `login shell` no `rc-files` (`.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` etc.) so probably no `$PATH` you expect to have.

To read more about the login shell check `man bash` and search for `-l` option explanation.

Comment: I don't know Jenkins but I would suggest to check as maybe it has an option to force login shell to be used.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: Hmm, there doesn't seem to be any options to change the way Jenkins connects over SSH in the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap `forever` with `bash -l -c` ?